# truthy and falsey values

Tags: scala

What are the rules for determining if an object is truthy/falsey in Scala? I've found many for other languages like Ruby, JavaScript, etc. but can't seem to find an authoritative list for Scala.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Only `Boolean` contains truth values.  Numbers, null, empty strings, etc. etc. etc. all are not `Boolean`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No data type in Scala coerces to `Boolean`.

So... `true` is truthy, and `false` is falsey. No other values can be used as booleans.

It can't get simpler than that.

Comment: Wellll, this being Scala, you can coerce things yourself: `implicit def intsAreBooleanHaHaHa(i: Int) = if (i==0) false else true`.  Not that it's a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why no one answered this before. @Aaron was right, but his answer out of the OP scope.

You can have all values coercing to boolean with implicit conversions like:

```
implicit def toBoolean(e: Int) = e != 0
implicit def toBoolean(e: String) = e != null && e != "false" && e != ""
  ...
```

But you can even have something better. To make types behave like javascript for your own types:

```
trait BooleanLike[T] {
  def isTrue(e: T): Boolean
}
implicit object IntBooleanLike extends BooleanLike[Int] {
  def isTrue(e: Int) = e != 0
}
implicit object StringBooleanLike extends BooleanLike[String] {
  def isTrue(e: String) = e != null && e != ""
}

implicit class RichBooleanLike[T : BooleanLike](e: T) {
  def ||[U >: T](other: =>U): U = if(implicitly[BooleanLike[T]].isTrue(e)) e else other
  def &&(other: =>T): T = if(implicitly[BooleanLike[T]].isTrue(e)) other else e
}
```

Now you can try it in the REPL, it really becomes like Javascript.

```
> 5 || 2
res0: Int = 5
> 0 || 2
res1: Int = 2
> 2 && 6
res1: Int = 6
> "" || "other string"
res2: String = "other string"
> val a: String = null; a || "other string"
a: String = null
res3: String = other string
```

This is why I love Scala.

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? When I try `5 || 2` in the Scala REPL in version 2.11.6, I get `<console>:8: error: value || is not a member of Int`.

Comment: Nevermind, I read your answer more thoroughly and realized that you added implicit conversions that allow things like `5 || 2` to work.

Comment: This is one of the more delightfully evil things I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

You're not finding it because no equivalent concept exists in Scala, although you can define something similar for yourself (and libraries such as [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) do just that). For example,

```
class Zero[T](v: T)

object Zero {
  implicit object EmptyString extends Zero("")
  implicit object NotANumber extends Zero(Double.NaN)
  implicit def none[T]: Zero[Option[T]] = new Zero(None)
}
```